# How to assign activities as tab content?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-listview, tabwidget

I found this custom TabWidget layout on the internet. The problem is, I dont know how to insert content into the tabs. Can someone help on this? Say I have activity1, activity2 and activity3. Heres the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TabHost mTabHost;

private void setupTabHost() {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setupTabHost();
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);

    setupTab(new TextView(this), "EASY");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "MEDIUM");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "INTENSE");
}

private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
    });
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You put content into activities by making their own files, declaring them in manifest and putting in their onCreate the `setContentView(R.layout.activitylayout);`. And if the content is static, it is wholely described in the appropriate layout.

Ok, understood. then return as `view` here public `View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}` that layout that you want to place there. Some listViewOfMyPictures or things.

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. I do understand how to set an activity as a content. I went throught the tutorial on the android dev site. But this is a custom tabwidget with different code than that of the tutorials. Can you tell me axactly how I code the "setContent" part for 3 different activities in my code?

Comment: I would return as view here public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;} that layout that you want to place there. Heven't you tried?

Comment: It is not correct. You should say What error do you see, how doesn't it works. Nobody will do your work here. Asking for that is very impolite. We all have our job to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the docs for [TabHost.TabSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html), in particular `setContent(Intent intent)`.

Create intents such as `Intent tabIntentA = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);` and pass them to the `setContent(...)` method.

**EDIT:**

Look at section 6 of the [Tab Layout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) - particularly this code...

```
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                    .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

You'd probably be better off following that tutorial anyway rather than the code you posted in your question.

Comment: Can you please take look at my code and tell me where exactly I have to input these?

Comment: Couldnt get it to work. Can you please just copy my code, paste in your code and post it here? I'll accept ur answer if it works.. -_-

Comment: Problem is that the tutorials doesnt provide a way to have custom tabwidget indicator. With the codes I provided, I am succesful to use a drawable as the tabwidgets indicator. If theres any way to use custom tab indicator in the regular tutorials code, I would use since the beginning.

Comment: @borislemke: So you're seriously saying you can't take the example in the tutorial I linked and combine it with the code you posted in your question? If that's the case then you're really going to have problems with writing any code. Nobody is here to write code for you - we all have to think for ourselves and learn how to solve problems. Your question title asks how to use activities as tab content - I've explained that. If you don't want to accept my answer or anyone else's then that's fine. Either way, learn how to experiment with stuff to learn how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Create an intent for the specific Activity, and add the intent via "setContent" to the tabSpec, instead of where you currently create a TabContentFactory - like so (copy/pasted from the [Hello Tabwidget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) tutorial in the Android Dev Guide):

```
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem and solved it by modifying the code as given below.

```
setupTab1(new TextView(this), "MEDIUM");
setupTab2(new TextView(this), "INTENSE");


private void setupTab1(final View view, final String tag) {

View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), string);

Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, DummyActivity1.class);
TabSpec tab1 = mTabHost
    .newTabSpec("TAB1")
    .setIndicator(tabview)
    .setContent(intent1);

mTabHost.addTab(tab1);
```

}

```
private void setupTab2(final View view, final String tag) {
View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), string);

Intent intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, DummyActivity2.class);
TabSpec tab2 = mTabHost
    .newTabSpec("TAB2")
    .setIndicator(tabview)
    .setContent(intent2);

mTabHost.addTab(tab2);
```

}

Previously we had setupTab() method for all Tabview. Now we have different setupTab() methods with different activity.

It worked for me .. ! Hope this may help you.